# Characteristics of Singularity Points

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning, singularity-theory

> Determine the character of the singularity at $z=0$ for each of the following functions:
>   \begin{align}
> &\frac{1/z^{7}}{e^{z}-1} \tag{1} \\
> &\frac{}{} \\
> &\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1}{z^{7}} \tag{2} \\
> &\frac{}{} \\
> &\frac{e^{z^{4}}-1}{z} \tag{3}
> \end{align}

I am currently reading *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering and Science* by Saff & Snider. This book provides a "summary" of the various equivalent characterizations of the three types of isolated singularities on p.284, theorem 18.

Based on this, I argue $(2)$ is an essential singularity since $|f(z)|$ neither is bounded near $0$ nor goes to infinity as $z \to 0$. Moreover,
I claim  $(1)$ will produce a pole, for $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to 0$.  Finally, I claim $(3)$ is a removable singularity for $f(z)$ has a limit as $z \to 0$, namely $0$.

Comment: Have you perchance swapped the functions for $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Wait a second… Oh yes! Is that right then?

Comment: As listed here, $(1)$ has a pole (of order $8$), and $(2)$ an essential singularity. (And $(3)$ indeed a removable singularity.)